# Apache Cordova and Angular - Android - How to take form input and put it into a contact object?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, android-contacts

I havent been able to find any good documentation on working with taking HTML form input angularJS.

What I want to do, is enter values in my HTML form, use those values to populate a contact object using the cordova contacts plugin, and then save it to my device.

Here is my horrible code so far I know I need to use ng-model and have tried before to set

`name.givenName = $scope.form.name` (obviously thats what I called `ng-model`)

```js
var droidSync = angular.module('droidSync', ['ionic', 'ngRoute']);

droidSync.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/main.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the manager page
    .when('/manager', {
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/addcontact.html',
        controller: 'managerController'
    })

    // route for the settings page
    .when('/settings', {
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/settings.html',
        controller: 'settingsController'
    });
});

droidSync.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {

});

droidSync.controller('managerController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.saveContact = function(){
        // create a new contact object
        var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
        contact.displayName = "Plumber";
        contact.nickname = "Plumber";            // specify both to support all devices

        // populate some fields
        var name = new ContactName();
        name.givenName = "Jane";
        name.familyName = "Doe";
        contact.name = name;

        // save to device
        contact.save(onSuccess, onError);
    }
});

droidSync.controller('settingsController', function ($scope) {

});
```

```html
<ion-content class="has-header"
    [scroll="true"]>
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
            <input type="text" id="txtFirstName"placeholder="Gary">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
            <input type="text" id="txtLastName" "McNeill">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Mobile</span>
            <input type="text" id="txtMobileNo" placeholder="12345665">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Home</span>
            <input type="text" id="txtHomeNo" placeholder="3214569">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Email</span>
            <input type="text" id="txtEmail"placeholder="gary@email.com">
        </label>
        <button id="btnSaveContact" class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="saveContact()">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

The core of the issue is not fully understanding scopes and models and how they interact but documentation has done little to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after days of research the answer seemed to be simple enough.

I had never initialized the contact model like this

```
$scope.contact = {};
```

Because of this, values were being taken from the form but could not be passed to a variable because `$scope.contact` was undefined.

Here is my final code for getting the First and Last names from the form

```js
droidSync.controller('managerController', function ($scope) {
    //Initialize model
    $scope.contact = {};

    $scope.saveContact = function () {
        // create a new contact object
        contact = navigator.contacts.create();
        contact.displayName = $scope.contact.firstName;

        // populate some fields
        var name = new ContactName();
        name.givenName = $scope.contact.firstName;
        name.familyName = $scope.contact.lastName;
        contact.name = name;

        // save to device
        contact.save();

        console.log("end of action");
    };
});
```

```html
<ion-content class="has-header"
    [scroll="true"]>
    <form>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Gary" ng-model="contact.firstName"/>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="McNeill" ng-model="contact.lastName"/>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Mobile</span>
            <input type="text" id="txtMobileNo" placeholder="00000000"/>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Home</span>
            <input type="text" id="txtHomeNo" placeholder="0009356"/>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Email</span>
            <input type="text" id="txtEmail" placeholder="gary@email.com"/>
        </label>
        <input class="button button-block button-balanced" type="submit" ng-click="saveContact(contact)" value="{{Test}}" />
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help.

You should use the  tag along with an  the input should 'submit', and ng-model should be passed as the parameter to the input.

```js
.controller('managerController', function($scope) {


 $scope.saveContact = function(contact){

  debugger;
        // create a new contact object
        var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
        contact.displayName = "Plumber";
        contact.nickname = "Plumber";            // specify both to support all devices

        // populate some fields
        var name = new ContactName();
        name.givenName = "Jane";
        name.familyName = "Doe";
        contact.name = name;

        // save to device
        contact.save(onSuccess, onError);
    }
})
```

```html
<ion-content class="has-header"
    [scroll="true"]>
    <form>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
            <input type="text" id="txtFirstName"placeholder="Gary" ng-model="contact.firstName">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
            <input type="text" id="txtLastName" "McNeill" ng-model="contact.lastName">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Mobile</span>
            <input type="text" id="txtMobileNo" placeholder=00000000">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Home</span>
            <input type="text" id="txtHomeNo" placeholder="0009356">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Email</span>
            <input type="text" id="txtEmail"placeholder="gary@email.com">
        </label>
            <input class="button button-block button-balanced"  type="submit" ng-click="saveContact(contact)" value="Save"/>

    </form>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ion-content class="has-header"
[scroll="true"]>
<form>
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
        <input type="text" id="txtFirstName"placeholder="Gary" ng-model="contact.firstName">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
        <input type="text" id="txtLastName" "McNeill" ng-model="contact.lastName">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Mobile</span>
        <input type="text" id="txtMobileNo" placeholder="654654654" ng-model="contact.mobile">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Home</span>
        <input type="text" id="txtHomeNo" placeholder="6546565654" ng-model="contact.tel">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Email</span>
        <input type="text" id="txtEmail"placeholder="gary@email.com" ng-model="contact.email">
    </label>
        <input class="button button-block button-balanced"  type="submit" ng-click="saveContact()" value="Save"/>

</form>
```

--- I imagine even this would suffice.

```
.controller('managerController', function($scope) {


$scope.saveContact = function(){
  console.log($scope.contact)
  //So to assign a new object a value from the scope
  var firstName = $scope.contact.firstName
}
```

--- should display each key:value in the contact {}.
I'm not sure of the object new ContactName() or how you are persisting the information... but now from the $scope.contact you will be able to extract any of the form field info.

Comment: I will try this once Im at home on my own machine and up date the question if it is not resolved thank you :)